# Tween shape position so it smoothly follows cursor instead of jumping?

Tags: animation, svg.js

How can I make the white rectangle continually and smoothly follow the cursor position using the move function with a tween?

What I've got so far doesn't work properly — the rectangle position only updates sporadically!

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesgreig/gaxrteoc/73/

```js
var width = 1200
var height = 800
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(width, height)

var building = draw.rect(1200, 800).fill('https://www.dropbox.com/s/pidx5gd1cmt3kyx/mcw_elevation_small.jpg?raw=1')

var rect1 = draw.rect(300,80).fill('#FFF')
rect1.center(width/2, height/2)

var mask2 = draw.mask().add(rect1)
building.maskWith(mask2)

///////

var xPos = 300;
var yPos = 600;

onmousemove = function(e){
 xPos = e.clientX
 yPos = e.clientY
  console.log(xPos+' , '+yPos)
}

/////

function update(dt) {
  // move the rectangle towards the cursor 
  rect1.animate(300).move(xPos - 300, yPos - 80)
}

///////

var lastTime, animFrame;

function callback(ms) {
  // we get passed a timestamp in milliseconds
  // we use it to determine how much time has passed since the last call

  if (lastTime) {
    update((ms-lastTime)/1000) // call update and pass delta time in seconds
  }

  lastTime = ms
  animFrame = requestAnimationFrame(callback)
}

callback()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## TL;DR
>
> Don't use animations at all (solution 2) or use the new svg.js v3 controllers (solution 3)

When you call `animate()` on an element multiple times, the animation gets chained. You call animate with every `requestAnimationFrame` which means you chain a new animation ever 16ms. That ofc looks very off because all animations are played after each other.

There are multiple solutions to your problem:

**Maybe the simplest but maybe not what you want (even if you think so)**

svg.js v2

- stop the animation before you call `animate`. In your case you need `stop(finishAnimation=false, clearQueue=true)`. The next call to animate then should queue a new animation and immediately play it

svg.js v3

- in svg.js v3 `animate()` returns a runner which is scheduled on the elements animation timeline. Before you `animate()` again, you should remove the runner from the timeline first for performance reasons:

```
var runner = el.animate()
// later
runner.unschedule()
```

- However, this is not required. Then you can schedule a new animation by using the new syntax of `animate(duration, delay, when)`. You want `animate(300, 0, 'now')`. This will run the new animation right away

**Maybe the solution you want but not have been searching for**

Don't animate at all. You want to highlight a certain area of a building in your example. Just tie the rectangle to your mouseposition directly:

```
SVG.on(document, 'mousemove', (e) => {
  // This function converts the mouse coordinates
  // into the space of the draw element. No other math required :)
  const {x, y} = draw.point(e.clientX, e.clientY)
  rect.center(x, y)
})
```

**The coolest and newest solution - but maybe you want consider the second solution anyway**

svg.js v3 comes with a new type of animations called declaritive animations.
A controller is in charge to always bring the animation where you want it at that moment making mouse following a real breeze.

```
// Spring() creates a new controller behaving like a physical spring
// You can pass 2 parameters: new SVG.Spring(settleTime, overshoot)
// So if you want jiggling increase the overwhoot (0-20% is useful)
const runner = rect1.animate(new SVG.Spring())

// This part is similar to the second solution
SVG.on(document, 'mousemove', (e) => {
  const {x, y} = draw.point(e.clientX, e.clientY)
  runner.center(x, y)
})
```

For more information about svg.js v3, twitter is the best source atm because code examples are posted every day until xmas: https://twitter.com/svg_js

Comment: Thank you — I got it working at https://codepen.io/greig/pen/YdKddb using v3 and SVG.Spring() :) :) :)

Comment: Awesome! If you have any questions regarding the new apiyhead over to our gitter chat!